# how to uninstall a package that was installed with --save keyword

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-package

I'm working on a react js project with this spec:

```
node -v --> v16.15.1
npm -v --> 8.11.0
```

I usually install packages with `npm install package-name --legacy-peer-deps` and uninstall it with `npm uninstall package-name --legacy-peer-deps` which usually works fine.. but in one of the recent package I installed, I copied the command from the website and I remember there was `--save` keyword in it. now I want to uninstall it since I don't use it anymore so I ran this commands:

```
npm uninstall package-name --legacy-peer-deps
npm uninstall package-name --save --legacy-peer-deps
```

but the package name is still in the `package.json` file. what should I do to completely remove the package from my react js appliation?

Comment: For a quick solution just remove package name form `package.json` from dependencies.

Comment: `--save` does not do anything special anymore, it is now the default behavior so same thing happens whether you use it or not.  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-meaning-of-save-for-npm-install/

Answer (score 0):

remove it from your package.json and run npm install